# How to check if array contains certain property in object?

Tags: php

I have this JSON array that looks like this:

```
[
 {
    "id": 10,
    "title": "book"
 },
 {
    "id": 24,
    "title": "cars"
 },
 {
    "id": 52,
    "title": "houses"
 }
]
```

I want to get the id of an object that has a title of "cars". The simplest way of doing this will be by looping through it like this:

```
    $customer_id = 0;
    foreach($arr as $value) {
        if($value->title === 'cars'){
            $customer_id = $value->id; // 24
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way of doing this (maybe without having to use the foreach function)? assuming that the array contains hundreds of objects and titles are unique.

Comment: its javascript object not php

Comment: @smart-googler its actually a JSON object that comes back and I'm simply looping through it. Do you know if PHP has a simple way of searching for the value of property in an object array so I don't have to use the foreach?

Comment: thats a good way to do this, you done it right

Comment: yes it is possible with `array_filter()`

Comment: @smart-googler can you provide a simple solution? thank you

Comment: if you want to use this library : https://github.com/bdelespierre/php-underscore#find

Comment: @progx I've added an answer for you. Have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try try like this but `foreach()` or `for()` is good enough :)

```
<?php
    $json = '[{"id": 10, "title": "book"},{"id": 24,"title": "cars"},{"id": 52,    "title": "houses"}]';
    $array = json_decode($json,1);
    $title = 'cars';
    $result = array_filter($array, function ($element) use ($title) { return ($element['title'] == $title); });
    echo array_column($result,'id')[0];
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/MgKIL

**Typical** `foreach()` with `break;` also do the trick for you.

```
$id=0;
foreach($array as $element){
    if($element['title']=='cars'){
        $id = $element['id'];
        break;
    }
}
echo $id;
```